# cancel button on search bar does not cancel correctly

Tags: objective-c

I have a search bar, i can search now, but when I enter a text to search, and click the cancel button. It does not give me back my first stage, meaning full of the items in the table.

For example: I search the item with word: a, it gives me all the a items, yes, it is right now, but when i hit the cancel button, i want the programme gives me all the items exist, not just a items.

Here is the code: please help me out. Thank you so much.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    letUserSelectRow = YES;
    searching = NO;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    NSLog(@"what text after cancel now: %@", searchBar.text);

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
- (NSMutableArray *) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSLog(@"search text: %@", searchText);
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dTemp in arrayData)
    {
        NSString *tempStr = [dTemp objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"sTemp string: %@",[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempStr]);
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [tempStr rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"1 count :%d", [resultArray count]);
            [resultArray addObject:dTemp];
            NSLog(@"2 count :%d", [resultArray count]);
            [tempArr addObject:resultArray];
            [resultArray release];

            resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        }

    }
    if (resultArray != nil) {
        [resultArray release];
    }


    return tempArr;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    NSLog(@"what text after cancel now: %@", searchBar.text);

    if([searchText length] > 0) {
        [sortedArray removeAllObjects];
        searching = YES;
        letUserSelectRow = YES;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        NSMutableArray *searchArray = [self searchTableView];
        sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:searchArray copyItems:YES];

        for (int i = 0; i<[sortedArray count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"this is the search array: %@", [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] class]);
        }

        NSLog(@"sorted array: %d", [sortedArray count]);
    }
    else {

        searching = NO;
        letUserSelectRow = NO;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override any of UISearchBar methods to accomplish this. The new way of doing this relies on the UISearchDisplay controller instead (specifically on `shouldReloadTableForSearchString`).

Declare your view controller to conform to `UISearchDisplayDelegate` protocol, and keep two instance variables: your model as `NSArray` (all data) and a filtered array as `NSMutableArray` (a subset of your data). The code you presently have in "searchTableView" would filter the content of the model and place it into the filtered `NSMutableArray`. Then you would override the following `UITableView` methods: `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. In each, before returning, make a comparison to determine whether your `tableView` argument is equal to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`. If it is, the user is looking at the filtered list and your should use the content of the filtered `NSMutableArray` to create the view, otherwise, the user is looking at the whole data set and you should use the content of the `NSArray` that holds your model. Take a look at the following Apple code for a simple example of what I described:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This is an old post but just for the records UISearchDisplayDelegate is deprecated in iOS8. it is now appropriate to use UISearchControllerDelegate. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/index.html